# JavaScript object code caching: which of these assertions are wrong?

Tags: javascript, performance, compiler-construction, v8

Because I have been around engineers for so many years, I know that if I don't provide context, I'm just going to get a hundred answers of the form "What are you trying to accomplish?" I am going to give the background which motivates my question. But **don't confuse the background context for the question I am asking**, which is specifically related to the JavaScript semantics that made object code uncacheable between padge requests. I am not going to give marks for advice on how to make my webapp faster. It's completely tangential to my question, which will probably only be answerable by someone who has worked on a JavaScript compiler or at least the compiler for a dynamic language.

Background:

I am trying to improve the performance of a web application. Among its many resources, it contains one enormous JavaScript file with 40k lines and 1.3million characters pre-minification. Post-minification it's still large, and it still adds about 100ms to the window.onload event when synchronously loaded, even when the source is cached client-side. (I have conclusively ruled out the possibility that the resource is not being cached by watching the request logs and observing that it is not being requested.)

After confirming that it's still slow after being cached, I started doing some research on JavaScript caching in the major browsers, and have learned that none of them cache object code.

---

My question is in the form of some hypothetical assertions based on this research. Please object to these assertions if they are wrong.

1. JavaScript object code is not cached in any modern browser.

   "Object code" can mean anything from a byte code representing a simple linearized parse tree all the way to [native machine code](https://developers.google.com/v8/design#mach_code).
2. JavaScript object code in a web browser is difficult to cache.

   In other words, even if you're including a cached JS source file in an external  tag, there is a linear cost to the inclusion of that script on a page, even if the script contains only function definitions, because all of that source needs to be compiled into an object code.
3. JavaScript object code is difficult to cache because JS source must evaluated in order to be compiled.

   Statements have the ability to affect the compilation of downstream statements in a dynamic way that is difficult to statically analyze.

   3a. (3) is true mostly because of eval().
4. Evaluation can have side effects on the DOM.
5. *Therefore*, JavaScript source needs to be compiled on every page request.

Bonus question: do any modern browsers cache a parse tree for cached JS source files? If not, why not?

Edit: If all of these assertions are correct, then I will give the answer to anyone who can **expound on why they are correct,** for example, by providing a sample of JS code that couldn't be cached as object code and then explaining why not.

I appreciate the suggestions on how to proceed from here to make my app faster, and I mostly agree with them. But the knowledge gap that I'm trying to fill is related to JS object code caching.

Comment: No browser will cache the parsed JavaScript, to my knowledge.  If you're trying to improve the performance, the place to start is the code itself.  That's an enormous amount of code; what does it do? *edit* oh and all of your assertions look true to me.  JavaScript is a dynamic language. Parsing it is pretty fast; perhaps that code actually does work when it's evaluated. It's impossible to say without seeing it, and of course you can't really post a 40 thousand line file here :-)

Comment: The code mostly enhances the behavior of DOM elements with UI behavior. It's a big web app, there are a lot of widgets, and they have a lot of behavior. Only some small fraction of the widgets appear on any given page, but of course, the problem is that we don't know which fraction until we've loaded the DOM and groped it. And in order to grope it, we need to load the code which knows how to grope it. Which means we need to load all of the JS in order to know which parts of the JS are required. Even a system like RequireJS doesn't fix this. But that's a topic for another day.

Comment: Yes I understand that problem completely. I've got an application using a similar design approach. A thing to look for, perhaps, might be inefficiencies in searching the DOM, and opportunities to handle events for widget behaviors with event bubbling. One thing that can be really slow is attaching event handlers to table cell contents in big tables. Handling events at the `<table>` element via event bubbling can save a huge amount of time.

Comment: But this code doesn't do anything at all. If I wrap the whole module in a function () {}, causing all execution to be deferred, it still takes about 50ms /just to compile it/.

Comment: 3a. There are a number of reasons for that. `eval` is just the most commonly known. Things like the `Function` constructor, string-typed event listeners or even dynamic property access (`foo[bar]`) contribute to the problem. Last but not least: dynamic typing...

Comment: @Pointy: "you can't really post a 40 thousand line file here" - Could he?

Comment: @xyu well I guess he code but the real question is, "Can you post a 40K line file and have anybody actually read and understand it?" (for free) :-)

Comment: @Pointy: Who said anything about reading (or understanding)?

Comment: @xyu ha ha well nobody I guess - what I meant to say is that the mere ability to squeeze a big pile of code into a Stackoverflow question is only meaningful if it's also likely that anybody would study it.

Comment: There is no reason to post the code. It has 0 relevance to the question at hand.

Answer (score 7):

You're right in that it's dynamically compiled and evaluated.
You're right that it must be.

Your recourse isn't in trying to make that compile-time smaller.
It needs to be about loading less to begin with, doing the bare-minimum to get the user-experience visible, then doing the bare minimum to add core functionality in a modular fashion, then lazily (either on a timer, or as-requested by the end-user) loading in additional features, functionality and flourishes.

If your program is 10,000 lines of procedural code, then you've got a problem.
I'm hoping it's not ***all*** procedural.

So break it up.  It means a slower 1st-page load.  But on subsequent requests, it might mean much faster response-times as far as what the user perceives as "running", even though it will take longer to get to 100% functional.

It's all about the user's perception of "speed" and "responsiveness", and not about the shortest line to 100% functional.

JavaScript, in a single-threaded format, can't both do that ***and*** be responsive.
So be responsive first.

PS: ***Add a bootstrap***.  An ***intelligent*** bootstrap.
It should be able to discern which features are needed.
RequireJS is for loading dependencies.
Not for figuring out what your dependencies are.

An added benefit -- you can set a short-term cache on the bootstrap, which will point to versioned modules.
How is this a benefit?  Well, if you need to update a module, it's a simple process to update the version in the bootstrap.  When the bootstrap's cache expires, it points at the new module, which can have an infinite lifetime (because it's got a different name -- versioned or timestamped);

Comment: I'm already convinced of the necessity of a bootstrap step, given that my premises are true. I was hoping to have a little bit more explanation / elucidation on those premises before committing to a very expensive and disruptive process of modularization. I already believe these things are true, but in the spirit of due diligence, I'd like to have a deeper conceptual grasp of why they are true. Besides, this is a great teaching moment!

Comment: It's not something which can be shown mathematically, except to say that even delays of 100ms or less can be perceived as lag.  But your ultimate goal is to involve the users, correct?  Otherwise, why have all of the widgets? So even if the code takes longer to get there, if the UI is *always* responsive, and is always providing some sort of feedback, as progress happens, a user will be more comfortable with the streaming, than with gaps in UI-response.  Google has some decent talks on these concepts.  There was one at Google IO 2012, called "How we Make JavaScript Widgets Scream".

Comment: They cover a lot of what you've suggested is a problem.  While I didn't find the talk itself to be that inspiring, they've got some good information in there.  My advice to you, without looking at what you've got, is to break your files down into self-contained blocks.  If you've got Widget-A and Widget-B, et cetera, plus Lib-A and Lib-B...  ...instead of turning it into a 40k-line monster, leave all of them separated, with far-future expires.  Version their names (date or version number).  Create a bootstrap which knows just enough about your environment to be able to compile a list of

Comment: required modules, and immediately start streaming them in.  As each module is loaded and compiled (when you get to this amount of code, the compile time is the one that gets you), provide feedback within that widget.  So initialize them, one at a time, as they arrive (as long as their dependencies are met -- and here's where you want a module pattern[actual modules/sockets, not the "revealing-module"/IIFE], a promise pattern, a mediator pattern, RequireJS or whatever will help you manage the initialization).

Comment: @masonk You can go even further and break it down into sub-modules, where if your weather widget, say, has local weather, but also has an international weather panel, which for some reason has features that don't need to be loaded, in order to run the local weather, then you can lazy-load those features when a person clicks to go to the "international" tab.  There will be a pause while it's loaded and compiled, but if that's async, and there's a CSS transition between tabs, instead of sync and pop-in, they'll never notice.

Comment: @masonk To why browsers don't cache a compiled object graph...  This is just common-sense in JS.  With late-static-bindings (deciding what "this" is, at the last possible moment), with closures and lambdas, a dependency on the DOM, a complete lack of source-maps...  ...all add up to context which could change on any page, at any time, for any reason.  If the language were not compiled at runtime, it would likely have suffered the exact same fate as Java applets...  ...which, funnily enough, failed, due to their strict, static, slow-to-load nature.

Comment: If it's so obvious, then prove it. Provide one example of a piece of code that must be compiled on every page load, and explain why, and I'll consider the question answered. I've tried to invent one and I can't.

Comment: @masonk Does that mean that all browsers need to create the same `document.documentElement`, `document.body`, `document.head`, et cetera, on each page?  Do all of those elements always need to be the same object?  If you're caching a graph of pre-compiled objects, then do those need to be precompiled, too, to sit inside of that graph?  What if you're loading the same script across multiple domains?  What if you're loading jQuery from Google's site (cached in your browser) -- does that mean that the API needs to change again?

Comment: I realize.  However, you're asking for pre-compiled code to coexist with dynamically-created DOM objects, using the same, current API, which is also to be fully backwards-compatible, in such a way that your object-graph exists as-is, cached from resources which may be obfuscated, combined, lazy-loaded, or any combination thereof, with access to dynamically-generated values...  If we were in a compiled language, and everything was done using dependency-injection, this could work.  If not, you'd have a very angry program, as soon as you tried to do something like dynamically-generated mash-ups.

Comment: @masonk of course, we aren't talking about introducing dependency-injection into everything, because at that point, it would require a fundamental change in the API.  In how many games can you allow a user to make selections which cause the game to download another game's classes, and run with those?  In how many of those cases would you expect compiled (non-interpreted) performance from those?  Even what you can do in the console, itself, would have an impact on that cached object-graph.  Meanwhile, enterprises are looking for ways to make pre-compiled languages ***MORE DYNAMIC***, currently.

Comment: The intent of a lot of newer enterprise business frameworks is to create entity/service - based logic layers, which take a performance hit, because of all of the polymorphism and messages (mediator patterns, frequently).  Refactoring to remove the dynamic-aspect and improve performance would inadvertently kill user-driven analytics in these systems.  The added benefit of JS being fully-dynamic is that Google recompiles code on the fly, based on what you're passing where and how often.  If this was compiled once, cached, and never touched again, many performance benefits of V8 likely vanish.